# Is there an R function that can replace the code merge?

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have to merge two datasets, but the code "merge" is overloading my computer and it is taking too long to knit. Which code should I use instead?

Here's the code that I used so far:

```
brm_avrg <- merge(avrg, brm)
head(brm_avrg)
```

Comment: The [FAQ on merging data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061) offers many solutions. The `data.table` solutions are probably the most memory efficient. But make sure you are joining on unique keys...

Comment: Maybe coz you haven't specified the `by` column(s) to join on.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the FAQ on merging data in R and I ran the code "full_joint" in order to replace "merge". In order to do that I had to rename an existing common variable of the datasets.                                                                          Here's the code that I used:                                                            `codmun_renamed <- rename(brm, codmun = COD_MUN_IBGE)
brm_avrg <- full_join(codmun_renamed, avrg)
head(brm_avrg)`